# DocuSign developper account token expires in 8 hours

Tags: token, docusignapi, payment

I'm using docusign developper account to test docusign restapi. Howerver, the token provided expires in 8 hours. I wanna know if i pay for an api plan, will I get a token with longer expiration time?

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid not. Tokens in production also expire after 8 hours.
You would need to use the refresh_token to obtain a new token. This technique is part of OAuth security best practices. 
Here is an article that explains how to do this:
https://medium.com/brandsoft/using-a-refresh-token-to-obtain-an-access-token-from-docusign-3c297eb51886

Comment: i'm testing java code, when i request for a new jwt token via OAuth.OAuthToken oAuthToken = apiClient.requestJWTUserToken (
              CLIENT_ID,
                IMPERSONATED_USER_GUID,
                scopes,
                privateKeyBytes,
                TOKEN_EXPIRATION_IN_SECONDS);
But it returns 400 bad request
I didn't get the error exactly where.

Comment: that's a different issue, might want to ask in a different thread

Comment: this specific question about 8 hours was answered. Would you mind marking it?